# why c++ games are so simple compared to unity3d

Tags: c++, unity-game-engine

3D GAMES:- i know that are lots of big title games made with c++ but most of the games here on internet looks so simple like less quality graphics and simple physics but the games which made with unity looks really awsome with better graphics and physics and other things . so iam interested in making big open world games rather than small games and i planned to do certificate course in c++ so my question is it worth to learn it ? i know it takes lots of hard work but iam ready for it so can i create open world game in c++ is that possible ? also i want some positive answer.

Comment: Because Unity does all the boring stuff for you. (That's the whole point of it)

Answer (score 4):

The simple fact is that if you work from the ground up in C++, it takes a very, very long time to get the engine up and running to the point where you can even make a game at all. Unity does all the hard bit for you, so developers can just jump straight into making a game without bothering about the behind the scenes stuff.

I'll give you an example. Using Unity to load a character model with texture into a game scene is no issue at all. You just drag the resource into your folder hierarchy, and then drag that into the scene. Job done and it'll even have realistic lighting if enabled. In a custom built C++ engine, you have to write the file loader, the renderer, get to grips with shaders, understand matrix and vector maths at a minimum, etc, etc.

Simply put it takes a very long time to make a good looking game with a custom built C++ engine, so just because Unity made games often look nicer, that doesn't necessarily mean that the developer has put more effort in.

Comment: so in gaming company they are using unity3d or c++ ? a person told me that making c++ game is old way. now most of them using game engine to make games  so is that true? he also said that i dont need to learn c++ . learning just unity3d can make me work in gaming industry ?

Comment: That I'm afraid I don't really know. My understanding is that indie developers tend to use game engines such as Unity or Unreal, whilst larger/AAA studios use custom built engines. I also hope to go into the game development industry, which is why I am taking the time to get to grips with both my own custom built C++ engine as well as using the Unity engine. For a proper answer to your question I can only suggest inquiring with the kind of people who do the hiring for the specific part of the industry you hope to get into.

Comment: cool and so your planning to do degree in gaming in order to work in industry or going to do it yourself?

Comment: Both, I intend to get a degree however I am working on doing the more difficult points such as learning the mathematics involved now so that it is easier when I get to university. Creating my own game engine is just to help me learn as, in my case at least, I remember these types of things far better when I am specifically applying them to a real world situation.

Comment: thats great and is it ok to start doing postgraduate degree in gaming after finishing undergraduate degree in different field? because iam going for undergraduate next year so iam planning to do certificate course in gaming  and then degree .

Comment: That I have literally no idea about I'm afraid. Frankly I find the whole university process a little convoluted, so you'll have to ask someone that's already been through the process rather than myself who's barely begun it.